# On-screen volume indicator is not showing up in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

When I press the volume buttons integrated on my keyboard, the on-screen volume indicator shown in the image below doesn't show up:

[image]

I've been experiencing this problem since I upgraded to Windows 10 Anniversary Edition. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Before digging in the main problem let me know first what brand of laptop are you using?

Comment: I am using HP 120-011in Desktop